# how to drag and drop PanelControl to another PanelControl on XtraForm in devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, devexpress

I have my application in c#(Visual Studio 2010) using devexpress 12.1 .  I have one XtraForm containing Two Panel. In first ControlPanel (Panel1) there are some components like edit text, check box, Label etc and Another ControlPanel(Panel2) is without any component.

I have to drag Panel1 and drop it into Panel2. 
I have created some samples in c# for drag and drop panel to panel using dragdrop, dragenter, mouseover events, but this is not working with DevExpress on XtraForm.

how to do it..
pls give me some suggestions..

Comment: by following  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407068/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-button-from-one-panel-to-another-panel it works