# Drag and drop in winforms

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I need to drag 6 images, which are in PictureBoxes, to 6 answer panels, one at a time and if the correct image is dragged to the correct spot it adds 1 to the score which is in a class called 'score'. There is code below to show one of the pcitures working but the form lags alot and if the image is dragged anywhere above the panel, it will snap into place. is there a way to stop this?

```
namespace DragAndDropQuiz
```

{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
    }

    private void pcBxLiverpool_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }

    private void pcBxLiverpool_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;

    private void pcBxGeneral_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            xPos = e.X;
            yPos = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pcBxGeneral_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ((PictureBox)sender).Top += (e.Y - yPos);
                ((PictureBox)sender).Left += (e.X - xPos);
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    private void pcBxGeneral_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                PictureBox answer = (PictureBox)sender;

                if (answer.Location.X < pnlAnswer.Location.X)
                {
                    if (answer.Location.X + answer.Width > pnlAnswer.Location.X)
                    {
                        if ((answer.Location.X + answer.Width) < pnlAnswer.Location.X + pnlAnswer.Width)
                        {
                            answer.Location = pnlAnswer.Location;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (answer.Location.X > pnlAnswer.Location.X)
                {
                    if (answer.Location.X < (pnlAnswer.Location.X + pnlAnswer.Width))
                    {
                        answer.Location = pnlAnswer.Location;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void groupBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       Graphics g = e.Graphics;
       g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), pnlAnswer.Location.X, pnlAnswer.Location.Y, pnlAnswer.Width, pnlAnswer.Height);
    }





}
```

}

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You should produce a complete reproductible example to increase your chances of a valuable answer.

Comment: What is `groupBox2`? Why is a rectangle drawn on top of the answer panel every time it repaints? Can't you just leave the answer panel alone? Why isn't the Y position even considered, is it irrelevant? What is exactly the expected behavior?

Comment: groupBox2 is just what all the items are in. The rectangle is drawn purely for design purposes, I can't change the border on a panel. I want to be able to drag an image in a picture box over s panel and it to snap into place. This will be done 6 times as there will be 6 images.

Comment: You are reinventing drag and drop code that Microsoft already coded for you.  See [How to drag and drop a button from one panel to another panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11414007/719186)