# DragOver button not firing event c#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

As the title suggests i am having trouble getting a DragOver event to function correctly. I have over 100 buttons on a form and i want their colour to change when a picturebox is dragged over them. I have set all buttons AllowDrop = true and have included the code below in the method.

```
private void ShipOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    b.BackColor = Color.Green;
    label22.Text = "";
}
```

I do not see why this will not work. I also have a DragLeave method which simply changes the colour to a different one.

One thing to note is that the item i am dragging over the button is larger than the button itself. Not sure whether this will have an effect.

Comment: Code works as posted.  Do you have the event wired up: `button1.DragOver += ShipOver;`?

Comment: I don't, where does this need to happen as I have 100 buttons. I don't really want to have to write 100 lines of code.

Comment: Are all the buttons in the same container, like a form or a panel?  If so, you can easily loop the collection.

Comment: Yes they are. Do I need to wire up the event in the constructor.

Comment: Yes. You have to iterate over all buttons and add the event if you haven't done it in, for example, the xaml-file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire up the events to your method.  If all of the buttons are in a single panel, you can do something like this in your form's constructor:

```
foreach (Button b in panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
  b.DragOver += ShipOver;
}
```

Same principle applies to the DragLeave event.

Comment: Just tried putting everything into a panel (sorry thought i was using one but wasn't) and it stopped the drag /drop feature from working.

Comment: @JOsh Did you copy-paste?  That will sever the control's events from their methods.  Did you do something to the PictureBox control?

Comment: Yes i just copied and pasted it into the panel. I didn't change the picture box control at all when adding it to the panel.

Comment: @JOsh Anny events you had for those controls wired through the designer will have to be wired up again.  Next time, don't copy-paste controls, simply drag them into the new container.

Comment: I have now managed to get the drag/drop working (just pressed control Z and did what you suggested. However it still will not display a different colour. I have tried running in both debug and release mode and have tried moving the buttons away from each other to see if that has an effect but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @JOsh Make sure the button's FlatStyle property is Standard.  Also, for testing, try `b.Text = "dragged";`

Comment: Just tried what you suggested (in release and debug mode and moved textboxes about) and it still didn't work.

Comment: @JOsh It's hard to offer more help than there is already.  Try using these solutions in a new project to get it working, then find the differences in your existing project.

Comment: Could it have something to do with my computer. I just created a new project with no additional code other than that which you suggested and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JOsh No.  I can't see your computer, but remember to have the `AllowDrop = true` property on your buttons and the DoDragDrop code in your PictureBox.MouseDown method.

Comment: This is the only code that I have in my mousedown method for my picturebox 

`private void pictureClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            
            //Gets the position of Cursor on click
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            drag = true; //and enables drag boolean so that the picture can be dragged using pictureMove method.
        }`

Comment: @JOsh You aren't calling DoDragDrop?

Comment: OK. I just added in the DoDragDrop code and got it working somwhat. It will now work but it only works when i hold the mouse button down. When i do this it comes up with the cannot paste symbol and does not move the image itself.

In terms of usability i feel it worked better before i added the DoDropCode in.

Comment: @JOsh See [How to drag and drop a button from one panel to another panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11414007/719186) for the basics.