# Drag/Drop Label onto FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

Im trying to drag a label from a FlowLayoutPanel to another FlowLayoutPanel.Im able to drag but it wont drop the label?

My Code

```
    private void flp_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Link) != 0

        && e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
    }

    private void flp_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Label)))
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel destination = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
            Control control = (Control)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Label));
            destination.Controls.Add(control);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop((sender as Label).Text, DragDropEffects.Link);
    }
```

Comment: You are dragging the text of the label but expecting the label to be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Name` of the controls as drag data, and then when dropping, find the control by name and remove it from its parent controls collection and add it to target panel controls collection. To do so:

1. Set [`AllowDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) property for each control that is target of drop. The target controls in your example can be both `FlowLayoutPanel` controls.
2. Handle `MouseDown` event for each control that drag starts with it and in the handler call [`DoDragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) event of that control and set the data that you want to drag. The moving controls in your example are labels and the data here can be `Name` of control.
3. Handle [`DragEnetr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter(v=vs.110).aspx) event of each target of drag and set [`e.Effect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.effect(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if drop is allowed or not. Here is the place that you can check if drop is allowed. For example you can check if the data is string and the string is the name of a control.
4. Hanlde [`DragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) and use `GetData` method of [`e.Data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.data(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the data and perform the actions when drop. The action here is removing the control from its current parent and add it to the new parent.

**Code:**

Using the below code, if you assign `control_MouseDown` to `MouseDown` events of all labels and assign `panel_DragEnter` to `DragEnter` event of both flow layout panels and also assign `panel_DragDrop` to `DragDrop` event of both flow layout panels, you can move labels between both flow layout panels, also you can re order labels in a panel:

```
private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as Control;
    this.DoDragDrop(control.Name, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        return;

    var name = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
    var control = this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (control != null)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
}

private void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        return;

    var name = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
    var control = this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
        var panel = sender as FlowLayoutPanel;
        ((FlowLayoutPanel)sender).Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted :), how would i change the colour of the label depending on which panel is was in?

Comment: In `panel_DragDrop` you can check the `panel.Name` and decide based on the panel name. Also you can handle `ControlAdded` event for each panel and set the `e.Control.BackColor`.

Comment: Many Thanks, could you provide an example using your code above?

Comment: You are welcome :) changing the `BackColor` using `ControlAdded` event is not a big deal and can be easily done. We should keep this thread only about drag and drop to be more useful for future readers. The code: `private void panel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {    e.Control.BackColor = Color.Blue; }` do the same for your other flow layout panel and assign the event handlers. Probably you can solve the problem using this comment but if you need more help feel free to ask a question about changing the `BackColor` of control based on parent after drop :)

Comment: As another option, take a look at this post: [How to drag and drop a button from one panel to another panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407068/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-button-from-one-panel-to-another-panel)