# How to create a picturebox from a button and make it draggable

Tags: vb.net

i'm making on a new project and i want to make many panels but each panel must be movable via click and drag, how i can do it?

I want to make this:
User click button
Picturebox is generated
Picturebox can be moved by the user.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  See [How to drag and drop a button from one panel to another panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11414007/719186) to get started.

Comment: That's three questions in one. I feel like you should learn some more about VB.net or do a smaller project first. Take each step at a time and research each piece. Users on StackOverflow aren't usually very happy with questions like this.

Comment: I want to make a generated object draggable.