# Drag and Drop moving controls instead of copying

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two panels and one on load gets populate with controls. When the users drags the controls to the other panel it moves the control from the original panel to the new panel, I would rather like a copy to be made of the control and place in the other panel. I need to be able to drag the same control in to the panel multiple times.How can I go about achieving this? I have tried changing the drag effect to copy but this does not seem  to do the trick.

```
void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }



 void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        Button data = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button));
        FlowLayoutPanel _destination = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
        FlowLayoutPanel _source = (FlowLayoutPanel)data.Parent;

        if (_source != _destination)
        {
            // Add control to panel
            data.Size = new Size(_destination.Width, 85);
            _destination.Controls.Add(data);

            // Reorder
            Point p = _destination.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            var item = _destination.GetChildAtPoint(p);
            int index = _destination.Controls.GetChildIndex(item, false);
            _destination.Controls.SetChildIndex(data, index);

            // Invalidate to paint!
            _destination.Invalidate();
            _source.Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            // Just add the control to the new panel.
            // No need to remove from the other panel, this changes the Control.Parent property.
            Point p = _destination.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            var item = _destination.GetChildAtPoint(p);
            int index = _destination.Controls.GetChildIndex(item, false);
            _destination.Controls.SetChildIndex(data, index);
            _destination.Invalidate();
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no mechanism in Winforms to create a copy of a control.  The Control class has entirely too many properties, gets a lot worse when you have them nested.  You need to re-create the control(s) instead.  Be sure to have a method that creates the original panel, the one you want to drag.  And simply run that method again when the drag completes.  It needs two arguments, the Parent and the Location.

Comment: watch this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407068/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-button-from-one-panel-to-another-panel best regards,
jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the control, then you'll need to actually take a copy of the control being copied. The best place to do this is probably in the place where you change the mode from move to copy. You can either leave the copy in the original location and continue to move the original or move the copy.

So where you have:

```
Button data = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button));
```

you'll need to either clone the button or create a new `Button` and set the properties manually. Cloning would be the better solution.