# Setting a "mouseDown" bool using labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I was trying to set up a system to check if the mouse is clicked in a winforms application and have ended up doing this

```
private void lblChips_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    private void lblChips_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
```

**eight** times over (for each label).

Does anyone know if there's a more efficient way of doing this? I tried using

```
    private void frmGame4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)      
        {
            mouseDown = true;
        }

        private void frmGame4_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
```

but that doesnt work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If each handler does exactly the same thing, why don't you have all of the labels use the same handler?

Comment: Note that mouse up and mouse down might not come paired if you move the mouse in or out while pressed.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield im really sorry but would you be able to explain what this means? im pretty new to programming sorry

Comment: @LarsTech a drag and drop game using labels and picture boxes, when the labels are dropped, mousedown is set to false and the timer checks if the tag on the label is the same as the tag on the picturebox. if it is, it disables the ability to drag. its meant to prevent a user from randomly moving the label around to find the answer without knowing it (if that makes sense, its for coursework)

Comment: Not sure how your program works, but Drag and Drop is built in.  See [How to drag and drop a button from one panel to another panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11414007/719186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make two methods, one for mouse up and one for mouse down, like this:

```
private void labels_mouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
   mouseDown = true;
}

private void labels_mouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   mouseDown = false;
}
```

Then, link all the labels to these methods. You can also do this from Code:

```
label.mouseDown += labels_mouseDown;
label.mouseUp += labels_mouseUp;
```

This has to be done somewhere under the InitializeComponent(); method. You still have to do this for every label but in the end it's less code.

Comment: hey there, sorry for the delay in replying, but how do i link the labels to these methods?

Comment: Do the second step for every label

Answer (score 1):

this

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CollectFormControls(this);
        ControlList.Add(this);
        MergeEvents();
    }
    List<Control> ControlList = new List<Control>();
    private void CollectFormControls(Control c)
    {
        foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
        {
            ControlList.Add(control);
            CheckSubControls(control);
        }
    }
    private void CheckSubControls(Control control)
    {
        if (control.Controls.Count > -1)
        {
            CollectFormControls(control);
        }
    }
    private void MergeEvents()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ControlList.Count; i++)
        {
            ControlList[i].MouseDown += All_MouseDown;
            ControlList[i].MouseUp += All_MouseUp;
        }
    }
    public void All_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "up";
    }
    public void All_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "down";
    }
```

Comment: `foreach (Control control in this.Controls)` This will only find controls that are DIRECTLY contained by the form. If controls were in another container, like a Panel for instance, then they would not be found. You could write a RECURSIVE routine to fix this...

Comment: Simple : Collect all controls in list and merge events.

Comment: Welcome, Ilhan. Would you mind elaborating on the code bit further?